# How to list points from highest to lowest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

this code displays the points list randomly ,I want to display points list from the highest to the lowest.

```js
if (command == prefix + 'points') {
    if (!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission('EMBED_LINKS'))
        return message.channel.send(':no_entry: | I dont have Embed Links permission.');
    
    if (!args[1]) {
        if (!points)
            return message.channel.send(embed);
        
        var members = Object.values(points, null, 5);
        var memb = members.filter(m => m.points >= 1);
        if (memb.length == 0)
            return message.channel.send(embed);
        
        var x = 1;
        let pointsTop = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Points:')
        .setColor('#79758F')
        .setDescription(
            memb.sort(
                (second, first) => first.points > second.points
            )
            .slice(0, 10)
            .map(m => `<@${m.id}> \`${m.points}\``).join('\n')
        )
        message.channel.send({ embed: pointsTop });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sort functions should return numbers, not booleans

This is the only part of your code sample that matters:

```js
memb.sort(
    (second, first) => first.points > second.points
)
```

Your custom sort function returns a boolean. That's not how [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works.

- return a negative number if the first argument should sort before the second argument
- return a positive number if the second argument should sort before the first argument
- return 0 if neither belongs before the other

You probably want this:

```js
memb.sort(
    (first, second) => second.points - first.points
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-` in  `Array#sort()`

```
.setDescription(memb.sort((a, b) => a.points - b.points).slice(0, 10).map(m => `${m} \`${m.points}\``).join('\n');
```